# PuTTY Terminal Width Shrinks Automatically When Entered into Byobu

Tags: putty, byobu

I have set the PuTTY terminal screen dimensions in my session under PuTTY configuration - Window:

**Columns 150 and Rows:35**

Also, for the configuration: "When window is resized:" is set to: "**change the number of rows and columns**"

So everything is fine with the terminal, I can make it full screen and back to window, no problem.

**But when I enter into byobu, the width instantly shrinks to a smaller size!**

I think, byobu is enforcing PuTTY terminal to a new size.

Because if I set the PuTTY configuration "When window is resized:" is set to: "forbid resizing completely" it is ok, byobu does not change. The downside is that I can not go to fullscreen that case.

**Is there a way to set the byobu width just like PuTTY and make it permanent?**

Byoubu Version: screen 4.03.01 (GNU) 28-Jun-1
Ubuntu Version: 16.04
PuTTY Version: 0.70 in Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution I found while checking the options for something else.

Go to the PuTTY settings and apply these below and your terminal window will not resize:

```
        Window - When window is resized: Change the number of rows and columns.
        Terminal - Features - CHECK: Disable remote-controlled terminal resizing
```